# Bioconductor installation difficulty

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

recently I've changed a computer into a new one and suddenly I cannot install Bioconductor. I used this code, and this is what I get:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

Installing package into ‘\\uniwa.uwa.edu.au/userhome/students8/21891458/My Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/BiocInstaller_1.30.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 102191 bytes (99 KB)
downloaded 99 KB

package ‘BiocInstaller’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘BiocInstaller’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\21891458\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2DZpRQ\downloaded_packages
'biocLite.R' failed to install 'BiocInstaller', use 'install.packages("BiocInstaller",
  repos="https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc")' or 'install.packages("BiocInstaller",
  repos="http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc")'
```

The problem is it doesn't install it. I tried removing Bioconductor, I tried removing BiocInstaller and I tried even reinstalling Rstudio. None of this helped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add your `sessionInfo()`. Maybe admin rights privileges issue?

Comment: Also in addition to @zx8754 make sure you have enough space in that student directory. You may need to change the lib path, the function is `.libPaths()` to see where things get installed.